# Can one add a discrete set of functions to complete the bound states of the hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, hydrogen

Though being an infinite orthonormal set of functions, the bound states $\Psi_{nlm}$ of the hydrogen atom do not form a basis of the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ due to the continuous spectrum, i.e. the scattering states, which need to be included.

Is there a (constructive?) way to find a countable orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that it contains all hydrogen bound states as a subset? In other words, can one expand the set of bound state wave functions of the hydrogen atom by countably many functions which are orthogonal to all $\Psi_{nlm}$ such that the expanded set is a basis?

If the answer is yes, can one also give an explicit expression of the added wave functions?

Comment: I think the orthogonal complement subspace to a set of orthonormal functions must have a  basis but I don't know if there is (in general) a constructive proof when their number is not finite. You could ask that on math.SE . There might still be  a constructive proof for the specific case of eigenfunctions, but I have no idea.

Comment: I am quite sure, that the existence is not a problem. But maybe it is also explicitly known or possible to compute it explicitly.